# Magento 2.4.3p1 Paypal through braintree: pay later button missing

Tags: magento2, paypal, paylater

I have enabled Pay Later button from the Admin side but Pay Later Button is not showing. Am I missing something?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please check the logs

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to USA Server to check the Pay Later button. In some of the countries like India, Pay Later option is restricted and not showing due to IP restriction at Paypal's end.